# Why don't Kafka's seekToBeginning and seekToEnd work with assign?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Say, I want to check the offset of the first and last message in Kafka for a particular partition. My idea was to use the `assign(…)` method along with the `seekToBeginning(…)` and `seekToEnd(…)`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

If I set `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `"latest"`, the `seekToBeginning(…)` has no effect; if I set it to `"earliest"`, `seekToEnd(…)` doesn't work. It seems that the only thing that matters for my consumer is `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG`.

I've seen a similar topic but the problem dealt with the `subscribe()`, not with the `assign()` method. The proposed solution was to implement the `ConsumerRebalanceListner` and pass it as a parameter to the `subscribe()` method. Unfortunately, the `assign()` method has only one signature and can only take a list of topic partitions.

The question is: Is it possible to use the `seekToBeginning()` or `seekToEnd()` with the `assign()` method. If yes, how? If no, why?

A relevant fragment of my code:

```java
KafkaConsumer<String, ProtoMeasurement> consumer = createConsumer();
TopicPartition zeroP = new TopicPartition(TOPIC, 1);
List<TopicPartition> partitions = Collections.singletonList(zeroP);

consumer.assign(partitions);
consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);
long currOffsetPos = consumer.position(zeroP);
LOGGER.info("Current offset {}.", currOffsetPos);
ConsumerRecords<String, ProtoMeasurement> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
// ...
```

The logger prints the offset n, which is the biggest (latest) offset of the considered topic.

Comment: what are the versions of your client and cluster? Sounds like a bug...

Comment: I reinstalled and updated everything, and now it works. Apparently, it was a bug.

Comment: Scary! :) Thanks.

Comment: I have this problem on all versions above 2.2.2, with the MockConsumer.  2.2.2 and prior work fine.  I suspect MockConsumer is a poor stand-in for the real thing, and that means the test coverage for the Consumer specification is subpar, if they are not both using the same tests to ensure they behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that this behavior is buggy and inconsistent in the MockConsumer.   The docs say that they is lazy, but will trigger after a  position() call.  But that is not true for the MockConsumer.
In particular, I found that it works for MockConsumer between roughly 1.0 and 2.2.2, and is broken after 2.3.0

In its place, I have chosen to do the following instead, which works consistently in the MockConsumer and the real one:

```
// consistently working seed to beginning
consumer.beginningOffsets(partitions).forEach(consumer::seek);
// consistently working seed to end
consumer.endOffsets(partitions).forEach(consumer::seek);
```

This is a bit more dangerous if there are threads concurrently calling poll, but it works great in my case, where I just want manual control over the offset position when the application begins polling.

Answer (score 0):

> Say, I want to check the offset of the first and last message in Kafka
> for a particular partition

You can use [`beginningOffsets`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#beginningOffsets-java.util.Collection-) and [`endOffsets`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#endOffsets-java.util.Collection-) for that.

> The question is: Is it possible to use the `seekToBeginning()` or `seekToEnd()` with the assign()

You have to call `poll()` after a [`seekToBeginning`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seekToBeginning-java.util.Collection-) or [`seekToEnd`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seekToEnd-java.util.Collection-) :

*This function evaluates lazily, seeking to the first offset in all partitions only when poll(Duration) or position(TopicPartition) are called*

Comment: After 2.2.2 this is false.  Well, at least for the MockConsumer.  Perhaps the MockConsumer is bugged.   WIth 2.2.2 and before, I can call seekToBeginning, position, seekToEnd, position, and get the start and end offsets.  With 2.3.0 + this fails and the offset never changes.

Comment: @ScottCarey Please check if you are doing a poll() before seekXXX() so that a consumer first joins the group

Comment: With an assign use case, why is there a 'group' to join?  I just want to rewind to the start of what is present and read the position there.  The docs specifically say that the seekToXXX methods evaluate on poll() OR position().  poll() works, position() does not.  That is a bug.